# Base para la etimología de «hacerse el sueco»

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Leí ayer en un [artículo de Verne](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/06/18/articulo/1529314000_434663.html):

> Según el *Diccionario de dichos y frases hechas* de Alberto Buitrago, [...] la expresión "hacerse el sueco" no tendría que ver con los turistas nórdicos de los años 60, sino con la palabra latina *soccum*, origen del actual zueco, un zapato de madera que usaban los cómicos latinos y griegos, pero no los trágicos: “Era, pues, el calzado que tipificaba a los personajes graciosos, los que representan a personas vulgares o de poco entendimiento”.

Rápidamente me fui al DLE para comprobarlo, y ¡vaya si lo confirman! Llegando incluso al punto de añadir [toda una entrada separada de "sueco" solo para esta expresión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YdyEKEV).

> **sueco**<sup>1</sup>, **ca**
>
> 1. adj. Natural de Suecia, país de Europa. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a Suecia o a los suecos.
> 3. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al sueco (‖ lengua). *Léxico sueco.*
> 4. m. Lengua del grupo nórdico que se habla en Suecia y Finlandia.
>
> ---
>
> **sueco**<sup>2</sup>, **ca**
>   Del lat. *soccus* 'zueco'.
>
> **hacerse** alguien **el sueco**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Desentenderse de algo, fingir que no se entiende.

Sin embargo, si me voy al CORDE, sea buscando por ["el sueco"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=el%20sueco&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) o por ["el zueco"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=el%20zueco&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) no veo usos lo suficientemente antiguos (el que más, de apenas mitad del s. XIX) como para justificar que en este caso "sueco" sea algo distinto del gentilicio habitual.

¿En qué fuentes y análisis se basa entonces la etimología aceptada a día de hoy para esta expresión?

Comment: Añade zoquete https://www.fundacionlengua.com/es/hacerse-sueco/art/168/

Comment: Definición de "sueca" según el _Diccionario de Argot_ de Juan Manuel Oliver (1987): "Mujer extranjera, sea sueca o no, que acepta más fácilmente que las españolas tener relaciones sexuales".

Comment: Para hacer la pregunta más clara, ¿podrías incluir una definición y un ejemplo del uso de la frase?

Comment: @walen - I went ahead and inserted the text in your answer.  I don't have a link handy but SE likes cited text to be handled this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el diccionario de Autoridades vemos la siguiente definición para *zueco*:

> Figuradamente se llama la Poesía en estilo llano, y sin lo conceptuoso, y realzado del estilo heróico, con alusion à las comedias antiguas, que se representaban con zuecos, à distincion del Conthurno, que se usaba en las Tragedias, y otras representaciones heróicas. Aplicase tambien al discurso, ù dissertacion en prosa; pero en dicho estilo llano. Lat. *soccus*.

No hay definición para *sueco*, aunque algunos diccionarios del siglo XVII sí recogen *sueco* pero redirigiendo a *çueco*, así que busqúemoslo. Efectivamente vemos en el Nebrija que *çueco* era la forma de *soccus* por la época. Pero no hay rastro de la expresión.

Veo en el CORDE casos de la expresión en el siglo XIX:

> ¿A qué pronuncias su nombre? Valía más hacerse el sueco. (1841)

Y con la forma *zueco* en el siglo XX:

> Pero Dios, el lejano Dios, o no oyó nada, o si algo oyó, se hizo el zueco, como buen viejo lleno de mañas. (1916)

La expresión la registra el DLE desde su edición de 1817:

> HACERSE EL SUECO. f. fam. Hacerse el desentendido en alguna conversacion ó negocio de que se trata.

Pero no avisa de cuál es su etimología, y no se recoge nada parecido en la entrada de *zueco*, lo cual realmente despista un poco. Curiosamente, el *sueco* de la expresión compartió etimología en las sucesivas versiones del DLE hasta 1970, en la cual por primera vez el *sueco* de la expresión se separa en una entrada aparte de la del gentilicio, especificando que viene del latín *soccus*, 'tronco, tocón'. Por la fecha del cambio es probable que Corominas tenga algo que ver, pero en su diccionario etimológico abreviado no veo nada al respecto (no hay entrada para *sueco*, a ver si alguien que disponga de la versión completa puede arrojar algo de luz).

Como curiosidad, no ayuda nada a este razonamiento que la misma expresión en Bolivia sea *[hacerse el italiano](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=hacer)* (según el DAMER: "Hacerse el distraído o el desentendido").

Y tampoco sé si ayuda lo que acabo de leer en una ficha del *Fichero general*:

> La frase hacerse el sueco 'hacerse el sordo' origen s. XIX, aunque basada en frases populares como "hacerse el zueco", el zocato (el acorchado, el inservible), el que se hace como una zoca o tronco de árbol, inservible, debió influir en su popularización la personalidad del valenciano Bernat y Baldovi, abogado, escritor, diputado, que era de Suecia (llamados hipocorísticamente en tono festivo suecos, el sueco, a él le llamaban los diputados el sueco, publicó un periódico festivo y mordaz El Sueco, muy leido) y era sordo. Su vena humorística era grande, mordaz y famoso por sus réplicas oratorias: cuando le convenía "se hacía el sueco"... o decíase "hacerse el sueco" como él. La grafía castellana debería ser "hacerse el zueco", cf. "sordo como una soca".

Esto es interesante, dado que confirma que el origen debería ser *zueco*, pero que esta persona popularizó la versión con *sueco*. En todo caso, no me cuadra que la expresión *hacerse el sueco* venga recogida en el DLE desde 1817, y que esta persona viviera entre 1809 y 1864, por lo que si realmente influyó en su popularización, debió ser después de que la RAE la recogiera. Las referencias a esta persona en periódicos españoles fueron a partir de 1843 según la hemeroteca de la BNE.

Otra ficha insiste en que la etimología propuesta por la RAE hacia 1970 (la que decía que provenía de "tronco, tocón") es correcta, pero que el término se acabó mezclando con el gentilicio. Vamos, lo que ya imaginábamos.

Otras fichas defienden la separación de las etimologías argumentando que el uso de la expresión "hacerse el sueco" fue en sus inicios algo "vulgar y rural" (varias fichas mencionan Aragón como lugar de origen), por lo que creen poco probable que se aludiera al gentilicio, sino más bien a la influencia de palabras como *soca, soc*, 'tronco de árbol', en relación a que estos no oyen y se hacen los sordos. De hecho el DLE también recoge la expresión *[hacerse el soca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YBBVvGM)*.

Comment: @walen sí, siento que más que una respuesta haya sido una confirmación del punto en el que te encuentras. Sigo buscando información, no obstante...

Comment: Tiene sentido que _soca_ apareciera en Aragón, por su proximidad geográfica con el catalán, donde [_soca_](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0125887) es exactamente eso: "tronco del árbol".

Comment: Después de cuatro años trabajando con los suecos de Ericsson, puedo decir que el 'hacerse el sueco' es una realidad y no un mito. Tienen una habilidad innata para ignorarte cuando no quieren contestar o continuar con un tema. La realidad es así de cruda.